# How to use mvc routing url formate in .net core 1.0?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

In .net core, is it not possible to use mvc routing? I used this:

```
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Landing}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
```

and my action:

```
    public IActionResult Index(string profileId)
    {
        this.ProfileId = profileId;

        return View();
    }
```

but if I used url something like `/Profile/index?profileId=1` it works fine but if I use `/Profile/index/1` the action is not works. means `profileId` is null. Why that happens with me - is there anything I am missing?

I try to use `[FromQuery]` and `[FromRoute]` in index method but that is not also working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your route parameter is named `id` (not `profileId`) so either change the method to

```
public IActionResult Index(string id)
```

so it matches the route, or you can modify the the route definition to

```
template: "{controller=Landing}/{action=Index}/{profileId?}");
```

but that may affect other methods you have